# ffmpeg always gives me input/output error for the first time running the command

Tags: input, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, output

I'm using ffmpeg to push raspberrypi video feeds (CSI camera) to a nginx-RTMP server then the nginx push it to youtube.
My problem is, every time when I run the ffmpeg command, it always gives me input/out error. Then it is working fine when I run the exact same ffmpeg command for the 2nd time.
How do I resolve this problem?
I want to start the ffmpeg command in a script file and put the script in crontab so that it can start the live streaming automatically. But this error makes it impossible to do that.

my ffmpeg command is as below(change the real domain name to mydomain.com):

```
ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 512 -f v4l2  -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100  -input_format yuyv422 -video_size 1280x720 -framerate 30 -i /dev/video0 -vf eq=gamma=1.5:saturation=1.3 -c:v h264_omx -b:v 20480K -vsync 1 -g 16  -f flv rtmp://mydomain.com:1935/live/
```

the error log:

```
Input #1, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 474200.421802, bitrate: 442368 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 1280x720, 442368 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
rtmp://rtmp.simonliu.space:1935/live/: Input/output error
```

Comment: Although I still haven't figure out the reason of ffmpeg fails for the first time, I find a way to restart the ffmpeg in a screen session when it fails. Basically I follow [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196282/328431)

Comment: I am having the same issue, only the first time. Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Same here, once it runs, then is great, but first time does not connect, it hungs.  Working on a solution. Sometimes it takes more than one time to connect.

Answer (score 0):

My RTMP is fine, the problem is every time we run the ffmpeg command, most of the time gives input/out error the first time. When you do it manually two or three times, works fine when you run the exact same ffmpeg command. It sounds like some sort of out of sync or lost of initial signal or handshake, whatever, it gets stuck and when you Cntr-C break then gives you I/O error.

I found a workaround and it works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
NUMERO=$(pgrep -f salida/mystream.m3u8)
echo $NUMERO

MOD_TIME=`stat -c %Y /home/public_html/salida/mystream.m3u8`
RIGHTNOW=`date +%s`
HOW_LONG=`expr $RIGHTNOW - $MOD_TIME`
NUM_MINS=`expr $HOW_LONG / 60`
NUM_SECS=`expr $HOW_LONG % 60`

echo "$NUM_MINS minutes, $NUM_SECS seconds since modified."

if [[ $NUMERO == "" ]];
then
echo "Start new ffmpeg";
ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://www.yourdomain.com:1934/live -codec copy -preset ultrafast -crf 22 -threads 8 -f hls -hls_time 5 -hls_list_size 5 -hls_flags delete_segments /home/public_html/salida/mystream.m3u8
fi

if [[ $NUM_SECS -gt 10 ||  $NUM_MINS -gt 1 ]];
then
kill -9 $NUMERO
echo "Killed Stuck ffmpeg";
ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://www.yourdomain.com:1934/live -codec copy -preset ultrafast -crf 22 -threads 8 -f hls -hls_time 5 -hls_list_size 5 -hls_flags delete_segments /home/public_html/salida/mystream.m3u8
fi
```

**Explaining steps**: First you need to get the PID Number here:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
NUMERO=$(pgrep -f salida/mystream.m3u8)
echo $NUMERO
```

Then you need to get the file time created or modified:

```
MOD_TIME=`stat -c %Y /home/public_html/salida/mystream.m3u8`
RIGHTNOW=`date +%s`
HOW_LONG=`expr $RIGHTNOW - $MOD_TIME`
NUM_MINS=`expr $HOW_LONG / 60`
NUM_SECS=`expr $HOW_LONG % 60`

echo "$NUM_MINS minutes, $NUM_SECS seconds since modified."
```

If your PID does not exist then you run new FFMPEG:

```
if [[ $NUMERO == "" ]];
then
echo "Start new ffmpeg";
ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://www.yourdomain.com:1934/live -codec copy -preset ultrafast -crf 22 -threads 8 -f hls -hls_time 5 -hls_list_size 5 -hls_flags delete_segments /home/public_html/salida/mystream.m3u8
fi
```

If your PID exists, then check you time created file, if it is older than 10 seconds, then its probably stuck and you need to kill the PID and run a new FFMPEG again to restart service.

```
if [[ $NUM_SECS -gt 10 ||  $NUM_MINS -gt 1 ]];
then
kill -9 $NUMERO
echo "Killed Stuck ffmpeg";
ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://www.yourdomain.com:1934/live -codec copy -preset ultrafast -crf 22 -threads 8 -f hls -hls_time 5 -hls_list_size 5 -hls_flags delete_segments /home/public_html/salida/mystream.m3u8
fi
```

You need to put that on a cron and run it every minute or so. If it is running and a m3u8 or whatever file you are created (mp4, ts whatever) is less than 10 seconds old, then skips and keeps the previous FFMPEG command working fine.